# Prefix only some posts with a custom prefix

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm lost in the world of Wordpress rewrites and I'm hoping someone can help...

I'm creating two custom members areas from my site; users logged in as certain roles will be able to view certain posts, guests won't be able to see the posts.

There are two areas for members, let's call them `gold` and `silver`

The gold/silver members 'dashboards' will be at `http://example.com/gold` or `http://example.com/silver`

I want to create a rewrite rule for blog posts so that if you go to `http://example.com/gold/post-slug-here` you see the post with a name of `post-slug-here` (without redirecting to `http://example.com/post-slug-here`). I need to keep the URL so I know which area the user is in (some posts will be viewable in both)

I've tried...

```
add_action( 'init', 'members_area_single_rewrites' );
function members_area_single_rewrites() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
    // The regex to match the incoming URL
    'gold/(.+?)/?$',
    // The resulting internal URL
    'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]',
    // Add the rule to the top of the rewrite list
    'top' );
}
```

I am resaving in Settings -> Permalinks after every code change.

Now if I visit the URL, it finds the post, but redirects to the non-prefixed URL. What am I missing?

I am also not sure if I can add 'gold' or 'silver' as an `area` query_var so that I can then do something like `if (get_query_var('area') == 'gold')` which would be super helpful.

Comment: Could you create _gold_ and _silver_ as taxonomies (tags, categories, custom) and prefix the URL in general with that?

Comment: Don't `flush_rewrite_rules()` on `init`. Your rewrite rule probably isn't working and you're just experiencing the default behaviour. Either run the function once after activation or just manually flush them at Settings > Permalinks.

Comment: @JacobPeattie - OK, I had been just saving Permalinks before I added that line so I don't think that's the issue, but I've removed it now.

Comment: @kero Wouldn't the URL then have to be example.com/taxonomy-slug/gold/post-slug ? I could, but I don't really want to rely the admin to have to add every post to the correct taxonomy. At the moment they select whether it is a restricted post and which user roles should view it.

Comment: @Sarah You can remove taxonomy-slug and only have `/gold/post-slug` or `/silver/post-slug`. How does the admin currently select restriction? Simply couple the taxonomy on that and nothing changes for the admin, the system can by default add these (with a bit of custom code)

Comment: @kero How would I remove the taxonomy rewrite slug? Even if that's possible, single post pages don't normally keep taxonomy terms in their URL, do they? So it still wouldn't be in the single post URL?

Comment: @Sarah There are many ways. What you want to search for is "remove taxonomy base from URL". YOAST can do this and other plugins are available as well. It's a bit difficult to discuss this in comments. afaik if you don't set one, you'll still have `/post-slug`, if you set it, you get `/taxonomy-slug/post-slug`. Pages should remain at `/page-slug`